# Updating SLA via REST (PyOTRS)

Tags: rest, web-services, otrs

I'm working on a little project right now and therefor I tried to update the Service Level Agreement (SLA) of a ticket which has no SLA assigned yet, by using PyOTRS, but it didn't work. Getting the Information SLA or SLAID of a Ticket did work with this code:

```
from pyotrs import Client
client = Client("http://otrs.example.com", "root@localhost", "password")
client.session_create()
myticket = client.ticket_get_by_id("1")
print(myticket.field_get(("SLA")))
```

But Updating the SLA or SLAID didn't work with the following code (It worked for other attributes like Owner, Responsible, etc.). So my Question is, is it possible to update the SLA/SLAID and if yes, what am I doing wrong?

```
from pyotrs import Client
client = Client("http://otrs.example.com", "root@localhost", "password")
client.session_create()
myticket = client.ticket_update(1, SLAID="1")
```

This is the Error Message I get:

```
OTRS Error Code: TicketUpdate.InvalidParameter
OTRS Error Message: TicketUpdate: Ticket->SLAID or Ticket->SLA parameter is invalid!
```

Answer (score -1):

We faced the same issue and were able to solve it.
As a precondition, the SLA must be assigned to a Service in OTRS.
Afterwards you have to send SLAID and ServiceID to the system to get a ticket with SLA created.